# stacked percent bar chart ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I have a csv file with following data format

```
963669136  solved   lost_village desc
948902923  rejected donations      desc
208285984  open     lost_village   desc
208285984  solved   lost_village   desc
268433965  solved   lost_village   desc
464273209  open     feedback       desc
464273209  solved   feedback       desc
2571706944 solved   victory_points desc
```

I acquire the info in the following way

```
tickets = read.csv("~/materials/minor/hw02/data/tickets_new.csv")
```

I want to produce a stacked percent bar chart. 
However, I can only get this far:

```
ggplot() +  
geom_bar(data = game_tag, aes(x = tag, fill = status)) +
  coord_flip()
```

[The Bar chart I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPwbJ.png)
How can I make it percents on y instead of count.
I want the result looking something like that

[Like that that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dmmrz.png)

Any help is much appreciated!! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the package `scales`. This should work:

```
library(scales)

ggplot() +  
geom_bar(data = game_tag, aes(x = tag, fill = status), position="fill") +
coord_flip() +
scale_y_continuous(labels = percent_format())
```

Comment: Thanks! Now that works correctly.